# Setting the default value for enum parameter

Tags: c#

I have a method that accepts an enum value as an input parameter. How do I set the default value for this enum param?

Below code shows how I set it now but if no value defined while calling this method, it's not using the default value. It uses another value. Any idea why?

```
public string MyFunction(string param1, MyEnum param2 = MyEnum.MyDefaultValue)
{
   // Do something...
}
```

I call this function without specifying a value for `param2` -- see below:

```
... // Some code
var response = MyFunction("Hello World!"); // Purposely not specifying the param2 value so it uses the default one
```

When I hit my break point in `MyFunction` after calling it without specifying a value for `param2`, I see that it does NOT use the default value.

Any idea why?

Comment: It should be fine. Please provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem - ideally without needing to use the debugger at all. (Just a console app would be simplest.)

Comment: What value does the breakpoint show? `(MyEnum)0`?

Comment: One thing that might explain this - does `MyDefaultValue` have a numeric value which also has another name?

Comment: Can you share the full enum type definition?

Comment: @JamesFaix No. It seems to use the third item in my enum with a value of 3. Seems totally arbitrary.

Comment: @JonSkeet The only thing I can see is this: the default value is `BRM_Legacy` and there's an item before that one which is `BRM`. And it's choosing `BRM`.

Comment: agree it should work and as the skeet says is probably one possible reason, I added a fiddle to test it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/LNWLZD

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/coJpD.png

Comment: @CaiusJard try to put it in  ``Console.Writeline``:https://dotnetfiddle.net/DA2UT8

Comment: @CaiusJard try this : https://dotnetfiddle.net/DA2UT8

Comment: Solved the mystery! Totally my fault! I use `Dependency Injection` and `Inversion of Control` in my app. The default value was set to another value before I updated my code. When I did update it, I forgot to update the `Interface` method which was still using the old default value. Sorry for this nonsense and thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Sajid  But those enum values have the same integer value; what are you expecting C# to do, keep the name?

Comment: I've gotten snagged by this in the past too. Classes and interfaces having different default values. I've found its easier to maintain if only the interface sets defaults

Comment: @JamesFaix I didn't know if I could do that! Excellent advice. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, this turned out to be a different default value being set in an interface, and it was being applied by the dependency injector